# MYSQL get data from table and insert on new table with variable

Tags: mysql

I need to take the value in a table to generate a URL containing this value and insert it in a new table. Is it possible to use variables within MySQL to form this URL?

Example:

```
SELECT `identity_id`, `email` FROM `identities` WHERE 1
```

Output:   1  marcelo@test.com

With the ID and email in hand, I need to insert the HTML content below where the respective email for each ID says VARIABLE.

```
INSERT INTO `identities`(`html_signature`) VALUES ([<img src="https://example.com/images/VARIABLE.png" width="580" height="138">])
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select into` statement

```
INSERT INTO `identities` (`html_signatures`)
  SELECT CONCAT("<img src=\"https://example.com/images/", `email`, ".png\" width=\"580\" height=\"138\">") as html_signatures
  FROM `identities` WHERE 1
```

I'm not sure if `VARIABLE` represented the id, email, or both but you could change the `concat` function arguments as needed.

Comment: Result:  #1364 - Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Is that error from MySQL or somewhere else?